# Python numpy array concatenation

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a doubt in numpy array concatenation.

For eg,

If I have

```
a = [ 1, 2, 3]
b = [4, 5, 6, 7]
c= [5, 2]
```

Could I concatenate arrays of different size??? If so, How could it be possible?

Comment: `np.concatenate((a,b,c))`?

Comment: Same way you'd concatenate arrays of the same size.

Comment: When you say "concatenate", do you mean you want the result to be `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 5, 2]`, or do you want to create something like a [jagged array](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jagged_array) using `a`, `b` and `c` for the rows (so the rows have different lengths)?  It would help if you could put that information in the question.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser, No, I want the result to be: [1,2,3,\n,4,5,6,7\n,5,2]

Comment: Please add that, along with your comment to Ruhul Amin's answer, to the question.

Comment: @Dhara: That's not how either arrays or CSV work.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, You can using [numpy.concatenate](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html)

```
import numpy as np
a = [ 1, 2, 3]
b = [4, 5, 6, 7]
c= [5, 2]
d = np.concatenate((a, b, c))
```

Comment: My problem is: I want to merge numpy array as a csv file. I used :      np.savetxt("output-1.csv", final_array, fmt="%3.2f"). Since"final_array" contains rows of different sizes, it doesnot works

Comment: I want the result to be: [1,2,3,\n,4,5,6,7\n,5,2]